# How to find $[\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+\exp(a-bx^2)} dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Apparently the integral of

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+\exp(a-bx^2)} dx $$

is straightforward and has a compact analytical form (dependent on $a$ and $b$), when this approximation is used:

$$ \exp(-a) \ll 1. $$

How would one find this expression?

Comment: By the change of variable $u=e^{bx^2}$, the integral is exactly $$\frac1{2b}\left.\log(u+e^a)\right|_{u=1}^{u=e^b}=\frac1{2b}\log\left(\frac{e^a+e^b}{e^a+1}\right).$$ When $a\to+\infty$, a simple equivalent is $$\frac{e^b-1}{2b}e^{-a}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that $\exp(a-bx^2) = e^a \exp(-bx^2)$. Try making a substitution $t = bx^2$. Note then that the derivative of this will cancel with the $x$ on top, giving you something with the integrand of the form $1/(1+e^a\exp(-t))$. Since $e^{-a} \ll 1$, you can go with $e^a \gg 1$. The, since $e^{-t}$ is bounded above $0$ in your range, you can apply your approximation nicely, since

$$\frac{1}{1 + e^a e^{-t}} \sim \frac{1}{e^a e^{-t}} = e^{-a}e^t, $$

which is straight-forward to integrate. Note that you will have a factor of $b$, but I'm just giving the general method. I leave the exact calculation to you. :)